# Injective functions from $X1 \cup X2$ to Y1 $\cup Y2$ where every $x$ from $X1$ maps to $Y1$ and $X2$ maps to $Y2$

Tags: combinatorics, functions

Suppose $X1,X2,Y1,Y2$ are disjoint non-empty finite sets. The cardinalities $|X1|,|X2|,|Y1|,|Y2|=a,b,c,d$. Also, $a,b,c,d \geq 1$ and $\max(a,b) \leq \min(c,d)$. Call a function $f: X1 \cup X2 \to Y1 \cup Y2$ **non-mixing** if there doesn't exists $x_1\in X1, x_2\in X2$ and $i\in  \{1,2\}$ such that $f(x_1),f(x_2) \in Y_i$. This means that $f$ maps everything in $X1$ to $Y1$ and everything in $X2$ to $Y2$. How many such ***non-mixing, injective*** functions are there from $X1 \cup X2$ to Y1 $\cup Y2$

Comment: Welcome to MSE! What have you tried? We can help you better once we have an idea of what exactly you're struggling with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a function $f$ to be non-mixing, either $f$ maps all of $X_1$ to $Y_1$ and $X_2$ to $Y_2$ or it maps all of $X_1$ to $Y_2$ and $X_2$ to $Y_1$.

In the first case there are $\frac{c!}{(c-a)!}$ ways to injectively map the elements of $X_1$ into $Y_1$ since we have $c$ then $c-1$ choices and so on until the last element where we have $c-(a-1)$ choices . Similarly for $X_2$ and $Y_2$ there are $\frac{d!}{(d-b)!}$ ways. Because we can take any mapping of $X_1$ and with any mapping of $X_2$ we multiply these together to get $\frac{c!d!}{(c-a)!(d-b)!}$ ways in the first case.

Now the second case has a practically identical way of counting except matching $X_1$ with $Y_2$ and $X_2$ with $Y_1$. This case gives us $\frac{c!d!}{(c-b)!(d-a)!}$ ways.

Now we just add the two up and get a total of $\frac{c!d!}{(c-a)!(d-b)!} + \frac{c!d!}{(c-b)!(d-a)!} $ non-mixing injective functions.

Comment: I might be wrong but wouldn't the number of injective mappings from $X1$ to $Y1$ *not* be $c^a$. Because the function is one-to-one, the first element in $X1$ has $c$ possible mappings, the next one has $c-1$ then $c-2$ and so on until $c-a$. Then it would be something like $\frac{c!}{(c-a)!}$

Comment: Answer updated to reflect this interpretation of invective.